# I can't get this script to work properly to press a button when you press enter

Tags: javascript

I found this script, I tried inserting it as a separate JavaScript, and it didn't work.

```
$("search-box").keyup(function(event){
  if(event.keyCode == 13){
    $("submit").click();
  }
});
```

The code doesn't seem to work at all. I'm wondering how to fix this.

Comment: `$("submit")` _may_ not work because `submit` is not a valid HTML tag. Do you meant `$("input[type=submit]")`?

Comment: try placing it in `$(document).ready(function(){ /// place it here `

Comment: @miparnisari `$("search-box")` isn't valid either haha

Comment: While there are obvious problems with this, figuring out what would work needs to see the HTML you are using and where you are loading the JS into it.

Comment: Anddd here we go with the downvoting. It is obvious this person needs help and guidance. Not downvoting their question to oblivion.

Comment: You appear to be trying to use JavaScript to trigger a form submission when the enter key is pressed in a text field of some kind. Why? That is the default behaviour when you don't involve JavaScript.

Comment: Those are the IDs of the Search box and the Search button, submit is the Search Button's ID and search-box is the search box's ID.

Comment: So you need `$("#search-box")` and `$("#submit")` then. Read up on CSS selectors.

Comment: @ChaseMartin — https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-css-selectors/

Comment: @Quentin yeah I know, just fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I think search-box it's id of block, i'm right?

So:

```
document.getElementById("search-box").addEventListener("keypress",function(e) {

    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(code == 13) // I think it will work too: if( (e.keyCode || e.which) == 13)
        alert("Enter");

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;

}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Those are the IDs of the Search box and the Search button, submit is
>   the Search Button's ID and search-box is the search box's ID.

You need `$("#search-box")` and `$("#submit")` then. I suggest you read up on CSS selectors [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-css-selectors/).

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#id-of-the-search-box").keyup(function(event){
  if(event.keyCode == 13){
    $("#id-of-the-button").click();
  }
});
```

Obviously it would be easier to help if you would show us your html.